# OP Deleting Question Immediately After Answered?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently answered a question, [Classify stationary points of $f(x,y) =8x^3-3x^4+48xy-12y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056731/classify-stationary-points/2056738#2056738), and it was deleted immediately after answering.

I found previous posts like this, but this is very odd and seems like it should not be allowed.

Why is an OP able to delete something as soon as it is answered?

I realize it can not be deleted if it has upvotes, but it is deleted immediately after answering - where no one even has the opportunity.

Comment: Flag it. And, if/when you have the privilege vote to undelete.

Comment: Here are links to the [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2056731/timeline) and [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2056731/revisions) confirming that it was indeed deleted and undeleted. @JyrkiLahtonen I see that the last undelete vote was cast by a moderator. Are moderator undelete votes binding? (By which I mean - if a question was undeleted by a moderator, can regular users vote to delete it again? Can it be deleted by the OP or autodeleted? That is, assuming that all other conditions which allow deletion or delete vote are fulfilled.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ordinary users (with the required privileges) can vote to delete posts that were undeleted by a moderator. Only deletions by a moderator can't be reverted by ordinary users, undeleteions, closures, reopenings can.